# How can I prove that $\forall x \in D (P(x)\implies Q(X))$ is not equivalent to $(\forall x \in D, P(x))\implies (\forall x \in D, Q(X))$?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

How can I prove that $\forall x \in D (P(x)\implies Q(X))$ is not equivalent to $(\forall x \in D, P(x))\implies (\forall x \in D, Q(X))$?

Would I prove the negation of this?

$\big(\forall x \in D ,(P(x)\implies Q(x))\big) \iff \big((\forall x \in D, P(x))\implies (\forall x \in D, Q(x))\big)$

If so, how would I do that?

Comment: Why the variable for Q is in upper case? Are X and x different variables?

Comment: @Wore Oops. They are meant to be the same. I have updated the post.

Comment: Then, to show they are not equivalent it is enough to find a set $D$ and two predicates $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ in $D$ such that one of the propositions is true and the other is false.

Comment: Proving the negation would mean that those two formulas will never be both true or both false. What you want to prove is that sometimes (i.e. in some structures), one is false while the other is true. $\forall x, x = f(x)$ is not equivalent to $\top$ the true formula (because interpreting $f$ with something other that the identity will make $\forall x, x = f(x)$ false) but you can't prove the negation of $(\forall x, x = f(x))\iff \top$ because it is true when $f$ is interpreted as the identity.

Comment: Then, to show they are not equivalent it is enough to find a set $D$ and two predicates $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ in $D$ such that one of the propositions is true and the other is false. It might be good to notice that the proposition $[\forall x(P(x)) \Rightarrow \forall x(Q(x)) ]$ can be true in $D$, even if $\forall x(P(x))$ is false in $D$

Comment: @Wore That's what I was thinking at first, but I couldn't seem to find a set of variables that could work. Could you give me an example of a domain and predicates that would show them not to be equal?

Comment: I can give you the set: the natural numbers. What do you think $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ can be for this to work? Remember, you want that for a specific $x$, being in $P$ implies $Q$, but you also want $\forall x(P(x))$ to be false.

Comment: @Wore are you sure that they are actually not equivalent? I think they might be equivalent

Comment: I am sure, but the only possible counter examples are those cases that I described before: a proposition of the form ($A\Rightarrow B$ being true because $A$ is false. This kind of reasoning is highly not intuitive, and if you don't know it then is difficult to convince yourself. Recall the truth table for the proposition $A\Rightarrow B$, which is false only when A is true and B is false.

Answer (score 1):

It is true that, if all people are left-handed, then all people are Chinese (because the hypothesis, "all people are left-handed," is false and therefore implies every statement). But it is not true that all left-handed people are Chinese.

Comment: So the domain D is: "all people", P(x) is "x is left handed" and Q(x) is "x is chinese"?

Comment: @JohnSmith12345 Right.

Comment: I don't see how it makes sense then. LHS: "For all people, if a person is left handed, they are chinese" RHS: "If all people are left handed, then all people are chinese". How are those two not equivalent?

Comment: @JohnSmith12345 The LHS is false, and the RHS is true, so they are not equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Left to right is true; assume that P always implies Q. Then if P is universally true, then Q must also be, trivially. Right?

But right to left is false. Say D has two elements, A and B, and P is true only of A, while Q is true nowhere.

It is false that "P is universally true" so the implication "if P is always true, then Q is always true" holds. However, the left hand side is false: it requires "everything which satisfies P must also satisfy Q," so which is false (for A).

In general finite domains (usually very small!) are enough to find counterexamples for this sort of thing. In fact, properly stated, there is a theorem to this effect (since you're only talking about unary relationships) but I don't know any constructive bounds off the top of my head.

But to approach these problems, if you think two statements are inequivalent, just try different small finite domains until you find a counterexample (or accidentally convince yourself such an example is impossible).

Hope this helps!

(sorry for lack of TeX, I'm on mobile at the moment)